# Powershell Rename file by duplicating the last three characters

Tags: powershell

Is there an easier way to duplicate the last three characters in a filename in Powershell?
I have been using the following codes

To copy the entire name:

```bsh
dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.basename +$_.basename + $_.extension}
```

To remove the unwanted characters:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem  -Recurse | 
foreach { $_ | rename-item -newname ($_.Name -replace '(.{15})..(.+)','$1$2')  }
```

But was hoping for a less time consuming method?

Edit:
I want to repeat the last three characters; e.g.:

before:

```
00469-101236-01-V-3-20-001
```

after:

```
00469-101236-01-V-3-20-001 001
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) offers several [placeholders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions) to refer to what the regex matched in the substitution operand; `$&` refers to the entirety of the match<sup>[1]</sup>, and can be used here:

```
PS> '00469-101236-01-V-3-20-001' -replace '...$', '$& $&'
00469-101236-01-V-3-20-001 001
```

<sup>Instead of `'...$'`, you could also do `'.{3}$'`

Note that `$&` expands to `'001'`, i.e. the last 3 chars. The reason that the start of the filename - everything *before* the last 3 chars., `'00469-101236-01-V-3-20-'` - is also present is that `-replace` only replaces *the matching part* of the input string.</sup>

In the context of your command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { 
  ($_.BaseName -replace '...$', '$& $&') + $_.Extension 
} -Whatif
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

---

<sup>[1] You can alternatively use `$0` instead of `$&`, even though only `$&` is [*directly* documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions#substituting-the-entire-match); `$0` is modeled on [`$<n>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions#substituting-a-numbered-group), where `<n>` refers to the index of a *capture group* inside the regex (`(...)`), starting with `1` (`$1`).

That `$0` works like `$&` can be *inferred* from the [documentation of the underlying `Regex` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups): "If the regular expression engine can find a match, the first element of the GroupCollection object (the element at index `0`) returned by the `Groups` property contains a string that matches the entire regular expression pattern" - thanks, [marsze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2060966/marsze).

[This helpful regex documentation site](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacematch.html) contrasts the behavior of various regex engines.</sup>